# Ruby: what's the difference using property with colons and quotes

Tags: ruby

I'm a newbie on Ruby, just doing a fast upgrade in a existent project and I'm wondering what's the difference between object `record` and `to_validate`.

```
puts to_validated.class
# Hash
puts to_validated
# {"data"=>{"name"=>"david"}, "metadata"=>{"body_size"=>"16", "collector_ip"=>"172.22.0.1", "collector_timestamp"=>1579608324863, "event"=>"whatever", "version"=>"1.0"}}


puts record.class
# Hash
puts record
# {:data=>{"name"=>"david"}, :metadata=>{"body_size"=>"16", "collector_ip"=>"172.22.0.1", "collector_timestamp"=>1579610268940, "event"=>"default", "version"=>"1.0.0"}}
```

The only difference on those objects is colons on `data` and `metadata`. Is possible to convert colons into quotes?

I know it's a dumb question but I'm applying a fix in this project and using a third party library that is failing using `record` object.

Comment: _"convert colons into quotes"_ is like asking how to add quotes to `123` in order to get `"123"` when you actually want to convert an integer to a string :-) You want to convert a symbol (`:data`) into a string (`"data"`). Since those are hash keys, you probably want [`Hash#transform_keys!`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Hash.html#method-i-transform_keys-21)

Answer (score 3):

In Ruby hashes are a key value data structure. The keys can actually be a mix of any kind of objects:

```
hash_with_numerical_keys = {
  1 => 'A',
  2 => 'B',
  3 => 'C'
  3.5 => 'D'
}

hash_with_string_keys = {
  'a' => 1,
  'b' => 2,
  'c' => 3
}

hash_with_symbols = {
  :a => 1,
  :b => 2,
  :c => 3
}

# can also be declared as 
hash_with_symbols = {
  a: 1,
  b: 2,
  c: 3
}

hash_with_singletons = {
  nil => 0,
  true => 1,
  false => 2
}
```

Symbols are commonly used as only one instance of a symbol ever exists. They are thus really effective to compare. String keys mostly come into play when you're dealing with JSON or some kind of external data.

The hash you are looking at contains a mixture of string and symbol keys:

```
{:data=>{"name"=>"david"}, :metadata=>{"body_size"=>"16", "collector_ip"=>"172.22.0.1", "collector_timestamp"=>1579610268940, "event"=>"default", "version"=>"1.0.0"}}
```

In Ruby 2.5 you can use hash#transform_keys to change the keys into strings:

```
hash.transform_keys(&:to_s)
```

In earlier versions you can do:

```
hash.each_with_object({}) do |(k,v), new_hash|
  new_hash[k.to_s] = v
end
```

If you are using Rails or just ActiveSupport you can use [`Hash#stringify_keys`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Hash.html#method-i-stringify_keys), [`Hash#deep_stringify_keys`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Hash.html#method-i-deep_stringify_keys) or [`HashWithIndifferentAccess`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/HashWithIndifferentAccess.html)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`Hash.transform_keys`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Hash.html#method-i-transform_keys) which was introduced to Ruby in version 2.5 to change symbolized keys into strings:

```
record.transform_keys { |k| k.to_s }
```